# how to add a document in firestore with 'add' I got a ERROR? Vue js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I want to add a new document when you trigger the function (on click). It works with `.set()` but I want to make every new document when you post the form.

**This is the error code what I get now:**

[image]

I thought maybe there is what wrong with my connection but it seems good

**My database connection file**

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
import 'firebase/firestore'

 let config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: ""
  };
  
// Get a Firestore instance
export const db = firebase.initializeApp(config).firestore()
```

I tried to search on google but I couldn't find anything.

**AddProduct.vue only script**

```
<script>
/*eslint-disable-line*/import { db } from '../Database';
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default {
    firestore: {
        Products: db.collection('Products')
    },
    data() {
        return {
            sort: ['Fruit', 'Vegetable'],
            fruit: ['Apple', 'Bananan', 'Grape', 'Kiwi', 'Lemon', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Pineapple', 'Strawberry', 'Watermelon'],
            vegetable: ['Cabbage', 'Radish', 'Carrot', 'Parsnip', 'Lettuce', 'Green bean', 'Aubergine', 'Tomato', 'Cucumber', 'Sweet pepper'],
            quality: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
            cours: ['€', '$', '£', '₺'],
            random: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000),
            addProducts: {
                catogorie: '',
                product: '',
                quality: '',
                availability: '',
                cours: '',
                price: '',
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                companyName: '',
                email: '',
                location: '',
                country: '',
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async add() {
            var currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
            const res = await db.collection('Products').doc(currentUser + this.random).add({
                addProducts: this.addProducts
            });
            console.log(res)
        }
    },
    created() {
        console.log(this.random)
    }
}
</script>
```

**I am bad in draw but the red blocks must be the new documents of the same form but the data is diffrent.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is trying to call `add()` on a DocumentReference type object:

```
await db.collection('Products').doc(currentUser + this.random).add({
    addProducts: this.addProducts
});
```

That's not valid because [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) doesn't have a method called "add".

If you want to write a document using a DocumentReference, you should call [set()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set) instead.

```
await db.collection('Products').doc(currentUser + this.random).set({
    addProducts: this.addProducts
});
```

`add()` is a method on [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference), and it adds a document with a new randomly generated ID.  Since you are providing your own ID, this is not helpful.  However, if you would rather accept that random ID, you would write the code like this:

```
await db.collection('Products').add({
    addProducts: this.addProducts
});
```